# How to strip some form of new line character at end of parsed Jenkinsfile variable

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am wanting to pass variables between stages in a Jenkinsfile and am doing it as people suggest, by writing to a file then parsing it.

```
stage('1') {
  steps {
    sh "echo value > var.txt"
    script {
      VALUE = readFile('var.txt')
    }
  }
}

stage('2') {
  steps {
    sh "echo ${VALUE} && echo 'ok'"
  }
}
```

However, I am getting some form of new line character at the end of `${VALUE}` that means I am trying to execute 2 lines and the `&&` is causing the stage to barf.  I've tried piping through `tr -d '\r\n'`but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand the nature of the problem, but the `echo` command does ordinarily output a newline.  You can suppress that with the `-n` flag.

Comment: Sorry, the echo command was meant to be a placeholder for commands that output to stdout that I need to deal with. Is there a way of dealing with the result taken from readFile()?

Comment: You could call "trim()" on the value, but this entire venture is misguided in my view. I see no reason why you can't define a variable in the upper scope and just write to that in the first stage and then read from it in the second stage.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this problem as well for my Jenkins file that is a groovy script, and this is what helped me get rid of the EOL / CR characters at the end of the value I wanted to use:

```
VALUE = readFile('var.txt').trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than doing a `trim()`, you can also make `echo` not add a new line after the value by specifying the `-n` parameter for it. So do `sh "echo -n value > var.txt"` instead.