# Jenkinsfile adding newline to end of environment variable values

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, jenkins-groovy

I have the following Jenkinsfile, executing in a Linux container under Kubernetes. My Jenkins server is version 2.263.4 running on Windows 2012 R2. Any variable I define in my `environments` section shows up in the `sh` action with a newline at the end:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      label UUID.randomUUID().toString()
      yaml """
# ..snip...
"""
    }
  }

  environment {
    VAR1 = 'VALUE 1'
    VAR2 = 'VALUE 2'
  }

  stages {
    stage('One') {
      steps {
        container('docker') {
          sh 'echo -n "$PATH"'
          sh 'echo -n "$VAR1"'
          sh 'echo -n "$VAR2"'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which results in this output:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo -n /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo -n 'VALUE 1
'
VALUE 1
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo -n 'VALUE 2
'
VALUE 2
```

As you can see, the `PATH` environment variable has no newline in the shell command, but the two variables from the Jenkinsfile have newlines at the end of their command *and* are surrounded by single quotes, even though they are surrounded by double-quotes in my `sh` command.

The problem happens when I use these values as parameters to other commands. For example

```
sh 'git clone -b $BRANCH $REMOTE source'
```

Ends up running this command:

```
+ git clone -b 'BranchValue
  ' 'RemoteValue
+ ' source
```

***How do I get my environment variables to not have newlines at the end of their values?***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jenkins pipeline sh adding new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630765/jenkins-pipeline-sh-adding-new-line)

Comment: @KindStranger No. That’s the `sh‘ command adding a newline to the end of the output being captured in a variable.

Comment: I could not reproduce this in a normal pipeline, without docker. This is really strange

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue even without docker with such a simple Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Demo') {
            environment {
                POM_VERSION = sh(script: 'echo "2.5-SNAPSHOT"', returnStdout: true)
            }
            steps {
                echo "POM_VERSION '${POM_VERSION}'"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `sh` command indeed adds new line at the end of shell script's output. Jenkins console log looks like this (see ending quote ' at the beginning of new line):

```
[Pipeline] echo
POM_VERSION '2.5-SNAPSHOT
'
```

During troubleshooting I came across article [How to strip some form of new line character at end of parsed Jenkinsfile variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44144252/how-to-strip-some-form-of-new-line-character-at-end-of-parsed-jenkinsfile-variab).

It turned out that is was enough to call `trim()` on `sh`'s returned value like this:

```
POM_VERSION = sh(script: 'echo "2.5-SNAPSHOT"', returnStdout: true).trim()
```

Now the value of variable is the expected one

```
[Pipeline] echo
POM_VERSION '2.5-SNAPSHOT'
```

Jenkins version: 2.303.2